# Batch file not closed after being created and written to by Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, subprocess, popen

My code basically creates a `.bat` file, writes some text onto it, then runs it using `Popen`. But I get this error:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Here is what I've got:

```
def killProcesses(self):
    processlist = open("processes.txt")
    with open("kill.bat", "w") as batfile:
        batfile.write("""echo off
cls
""")
    batfile.close()
    for line in processlist:
        newbatfile = open("kill.bat","a")
        newdata = line.replace('\n','')
        newbatfile.write("""
Taskkill /IM """+newdata+""" /F""")
    p = Popen("kill.bat")
    stdout,stderr = p.communicate()
    processlist.close()
```

I did some research and I found adding `with` or `close()` to my code might resolve the problem, but it's not doing anything, I'm still getting the error. Am I doing something wrong? My guess is I didn't specify the exact file path, but the file is in the same directory as the python script so I feel as if I don't need to specify the exact path. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't close `newbatfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial batfile.close() call is unnecessary: the with block ensures that the file is closed when exiting the block. However, your later loop opens a new handle to the file on each pass through the loop and never closes them.  You might consider rewriting your loop to something like:

```
with open("kill.bat", "a") as newbatfile:
    for line in processlist:
        newdata  = line.replace("\n", "")
        newbatfile.write(...)
```

or better yet, just putting the loop inside the original with block.